# Getting UIRequredDeviceCapabilites error when validating app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store

I'm trying to validate my app for upload but getting the following error:

[image]

I have `armv6` and `armv7` under valid architectures.

Comment: What do you have in your `*-info.plist` under `Required device capabilities`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have added some new features in you application which won't work on some iOS devices, However you can still upload this app but you have to specify this in your plist that some of the feature will not run on lets say iPod so don't let user to install this application on iPod.

have a look at this description by apple, you may be able to debug this issue :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html

Cheers

Comment: @faisal, Hmmm I guess that is the problem, try to add "still-camera" to true and see if error goes.